# Return ArrayList and use it in another method

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, return

I have a method that returns an ArrayList of Objects. I return the arraylist created, and its filled with many objects, that I check they are there by printing them in the same method. When I use that Arraylist as parameter in another method, it gives me an error, like if the arraylist were empty.

Lets say the object its Position(y,x), with methods getFila and getColumna.
And the method that fails (actually does nothing):

```
public static ArrayList<Position> getTrayectory (ArrayList<Position> aListPos){
        for (int ii = 0; ii < aListPos.size();ii++ ) {
            System.out.println("(" +  aListPos.get(ii).getFila() + "," + aListPos.get(ii).getColumna()+")");
        }
        return aListPos;
    }
```

I return the Arraylist with many objects inside, but I dont know what is happening with that.

Summary:

```
1- I have a method that returns an ArryList
2- I create a new Arraylist with method in 1
3- I use new method with Arraylist in 2 as parameter.

(4-) Nothing happens, because new arraylist in 2 look empty.
```

Can anyone help me in the process?

Comment: Can you show the exact error and the code where your arraylist gets filled?

Comment: Im not with the computer right now. Does matter how the arraylist is filled? I know that is filled because I can itinerate trough it printing the values of each element. Anyway Ill paste here the code.

Comment: @AgusDG Can you explain these two items please `aListPos.get(ii).getFila()` and `aListPos.get(ii).getColumna()`

Comment: Sure. aListPos is the arraylist.It is type Object Position, so when I do .get(ii) I get the object of position ii, so the toString, but as I want the atributes of each Object of the arraylist I call the getFila and getColumna to call the atributes int Fila and int Columna of the object Position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the ArrayList in the (unseen) method that provides it, are you returning it? Or are you modifying a parameter?

In other words, are you doing this:

```
ArrayList<Position> myArrayList = generateArrayList(); // or whatever you call it
```

or are you doing this:

```
ArrayList<Position> myArrayList;
generateArrayList(myArrayList);
ArrayList<Position> result = getTrayjectory(myArrayList);
```

The second version of this won't work, because when you create an object inside a method, the only way that it can escape the method's bounds is to be returned by that method.  Otherwise, it goes out of scope when the method ends.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an IDE like eclipse, You can easily insert a break point in the problematic code and you can "watch" the contents of each variable.

So you can find out the exact point where your arraylist goes empty.

Comment: This should go as comment not answer. You are not explaining to him why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think your ArryList contain Position objects.  I don't know exactly so its just my guess.

```
       System.out.println("(" +  aListPos.get(ii).getFila() + "," 
       + ListPos.get(ii).getColumna()+")");
```

Instead. Try this

```
       System.out.println("(" +  (aListPos.get(ii)).getFila() + "," 
       + (ListPos.get(ii)).getColumna()+")");
```