# Problems with accessing classes inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, null

I think I got a similar problem like in this post: [Return ArrayList and use it in another method problm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944155/return-arraylist-and-use-it-in-another-method-problm/13944224#13944224).

In a several class an ArrayList<...> will be created with "new". In this List I store several DataContainer(defined by another class).

Now if I saved all my data classes, I return this List back to my Activity via "OnMessageReceived".

The strange thing is, sometimes it works but mostly I get an empty list.

I compressed the code for better view. If I debug I can see the data is accessible until it jumps into the method "public void messageReceived(final ArrayList _Container){...}"

Is that kind of returning not possible?

Some Code:

(Class 1) Method for getting Data:

```
public boolean run() {

    try {
        ...
        try {
            ....
            while (mRun) {                                                      
                if(in.ready()) {                        
                    ...
                    ...                 
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(_ConvertData.GetMessage(new String(Puffer).substring(0,length)));                      
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

(Class 2)

```
public ArrayList<DatenContainer> GetMessage(String message) {

    Sensoren SensorName = Sensoren.NONE;
    int _Length = 0;
    int _ID = 0;
    double _TimeStamp = 0;
    int _NumberOfPackage = 0;
    String _msg = "";       

    while (!message.isEmpty()) {
            ...
            ...
            Container.add(new DatenContainer(_Length, _ID, _TimeStamp, _NumberOfPackage, _msg, SensorName));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}              
    }
    return Container;
}
```

(Activity)

```
TCP_Client_Thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();

            try {
                // create a TCPClient object and
                mTcpClient = new TCP_Client(new TCP_Client.OnMessageReceived() {

                    @Override
                    //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                    public void messageReceived(final ArrayList<DatenContainer> _Container) {                                               

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {                                     

                                try {                                       
                                    for (DatenContainer datenContainer : _Container) {
                                    ...
                                    ...                                     
                                    }   
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Show_Toast(e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }                                                                           
                },Infos.getSERVERIP(),Infos.getSERVERPORT());               
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {}              
        }
```

Comment: Please construct a simple test-case.  All of this code with exceptions and TCP access, etc. is just hiding the issue...

Comment: Could you provide a link to all three classes in a zip?

Comment: It sounds like you're already mostly there.  If you've used a debugger to find the method in which the trouble occurs, you ought to be able to step through that method and find out when something unexpected happens to your container.  I had something similar happen to me and had to do a lot of step-wise debugging to track it down.  The problem was the inadvertant placement of a closing brace that included some initialization code that I did not want running for a particular case.  I just moved the brace to fix things.  Since you're nesting a -lot- of braces, this could feasibly be an issue.

Comment: @meewok http://www.tf-kiel.de/stuff/src.rar

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I will try to create a test-case

Comment: @scottb I don't see any wrong braces :(

Comment: Try the following (I want to verify it is not some kind of race condition). Put a `Thread.sleep(2000);` after `mMessageListener.messageReceived(_ConvertData.GetMessage(new String(Puffer).substring(0,length)));` on line 87 of TCP_client. Also, if you can add breakpoints to check that the list truly has data.

Comment: Here you will find a simple-case project: www.tf-kiel.de/stuff/small.rar

Comment: @Scuido ok..so with Thread.sleep() it doesn't work...

Comment: I tried to fetch the data before it starts the runOnUi-Thread. I can access the data until he starts the MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...} method. At this point the List gets "null"

Comment: Short Picture for showing the problem: [link](http://www.tf-kiel.de/stuff/method.png) .After joining the onUi-method Test is empty.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem, but why is DatenContainer a subclass of Convert_Data?

Comment: I see you are using multiple threads. I see no synchronization statements. So how do you guarantee that the modification made to the ArrayList by GetMessage are made visible to the other threads?

Comment: @gogognome To share some data and use some methods. Didn't want to program twice. Damn, probably you are right. I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I forgot the sync-method. Thx guys for helping me out :)

```
@Override
//here the messageReceived method is implemented
public void messageReceived(final ArrayList<DatenContainer> _Container) {                                               

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {                                     
            ArrayList<DatenContainer> Container;

            synchronized (_Container) {
                Container = _Container;
            }

            try {                                       
                if (Container != null && !Container.isEmpty()) {

                for(int i = 0; i < Container.size(); i++) {

                        DatenContainer datenContainer = (DatenContainer)Container.get(i);

                        switch (datenContainer.get_ActSensor()) {                                               
                        case SPEED: 
                            edt_3.setText(datenContainer.get_Data());
                            break;
                        case COG:   
                            edt_4.setText(datenContainer.get_Data());
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }                                                   
                    }   
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Show_Toast(e.toString());
            }

            Container.clear();
        }
    });
}
```